# C++ send data with GET

Tags: c++, http

I have this code, and I have this problems: 
Error   1   error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers
2   IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

I am trying to GET data to the test.php file, with the m_AccountID variable data, I tryed many things, but I got this two errors.

Any idea to fix it?:)

```
void ConnectEx::SendDataPHP(){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        //cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        //system("pause");
        return;
    }
    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname("www.mysite.com");
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    //cout << "Connecting...\n";
    if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
        //cout << "Could not connect";
        //system("pause");
        return;
    }

    //cout << "Connected.\n";

    send(Socket, "GET /api/test.php?username=" +m_AccountID+ "HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET /api/test.php?username="+m_AccountID+ "HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"), 0);
char buffer[10000];
int nDataLength;
while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0){
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
        //cout << buffer[i];
        i += 1;
    }
}
closesocket(Socket);
WSACleanup();
//system("pause");
    return;

}

class ConnectEx
{
public:
    void    SendDataPHP();
.
.
.
.
    char    m_AccountID[11];
.
.
.


}; extern ConnectEx gConnectEx;
```

Comment: change `char    m_AccountID[11];` to `std::string m_AccountID;`

Comment: I tryed before, still the same problems :)

Comment: put your string like this: `std::string( "GET /api/test.php?username=" + m_AccountID + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" ).c_str( )` but only for the first part

Comment: Same errors + 1 Error 2 error C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union

Comment: I've updated my post. Please also check if the errors actually appear in any of the lines you provided

Comment: Include in the code so still the same errors, I am going to sleep, because I am here about 30+ hours, so I need a litle bit sleep, if you will have any idea please share with me! :) Maybe after I wake up i will have some other.

Comment: On another page somebody wrote me I need to use strcat to make this.

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate it to the string:

```
send( Socket ,
      std::string( "GET /api/test.php?username=" + m_AccountID + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" ).c_str( ) , 
      strlen("GET /api/test.php?username=" + m_AccountID + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n") , 0);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/4QzzCh)

Also if you just repeat the string afterwards, save it to a variable first so you can reuse that.
And i wouldn't recommend using `std::strlen` since it's old.

Rather do it like this:

```
std::string m_AccountID;
std::string data;


m_AccountID = "12345";
data        = "GET /api/test.php?username=" + m_AccountID + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"

send( Socket , data.c_str( ) , data.size( ) , 0 );
```

`char    m_AccountID[11];` should be `std::string m_AccountID;`

Your code should be looking like this now:

```
void ConnectEx::SendDataPHP(){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        //cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        //system("pause");
        return;
    }
    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname("www.mysite.com");
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    //cout << "Connecting...\n";
    if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
        //cout << "Could not connect";
        //system("pause");
        return;
    }

    //cout << "Connected.\n";

    send(Socket, std::string( "GET /api/test.php?username=" +m_AccountID+ "HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" ).c_str( ) , strlen("GET /api/test.php?username="+m_AccountID+ "HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"), 0);
char buffer[10000];
int nDataLength;
while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0){
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
        //cout << buffer[i];
        i += 1;
    }
}
closesocket(Socket);
WSACleanup();
//system("pause");
    return;

}

class ConnectEx
{
public:
    void    SendDataPHP();
.
.
.
.
    std::string m_AccountID;
.
.
.


}; extern ConnectEx gConnectEx;
```

Make sure you also `#include <string>`

Comment: Error 1 error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers, Thats the 1st error, 2nd:  2 IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Comment: @Vbnetguy I'm guessing you're using cstrings? you should switch away from them. use normal strings unless you have a good reason

Comment: No.  I am not using, any another idea? I tryed the same and I get this error, thats why I asked here. I just thinked I made something bad, than I removed the + from the example, because I dont want looks like a retard. :)

Comment: @Vbnetguy try `send( Socket , data.c_str( ) , data.size( ) , 0 );` or just edit your question and provide lil bit more code

Comment: Thanks! I added more code and edited the original post!

Answer (score 0):

Now I made it, I used strcat to merge the variable than I put this into the send and its working. Thanks for the help!